# Why Can't I use all of my limits.memory and requests.memory in my DeploymentConfig in openshift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I want to deploy push gateway in an openshift cluster, I have these resource quotas in my namespace:
[image]

And I have defined my resources in the `DeploymentConfig` :

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pushgateway
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pushgateway
        image: prom/pushgateway
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9091
        resources:
         limits:
           memory: 4Gi
           cpu: 2
         requests:
           memory: 2Gi
           cpu: 2
```

But after applying the YAML file, I see the DeploymentConfig job is running but it is not creating any pushgateway pod, when I describe the DeploymenConfig I see Only normal events:

```
Events:
  Type      Reason          Age From                Message
  ----      ------          ----    ----                -------
  Normal    DeploymentCreated   25m deploymentconfig-controller Created new replication controller "pushgateway-deployment-1" for version 1
  Normal    DeploymentCreated   15m deploymentconfig-controller Created new replication controller "pushgateway-deployment-2" for version 2
```

I know if I increase the resource quota to 4Gb of ram and 4 CPU cores, the DeploymentConfig will create the pod but I don't understand the reason, it's like I'm sparing half of the resources.